# If a problem Q is NP complete, is another problem reducible to Q also NP complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

Let's say $\mathcal{P}$ is a yes/no prolem with an existing reduction to the problem $\mathcal{Q}$ (with time complexity $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$). $\mathcal{Q}$ is NP complete. Does this mean that $\mathcal{P}$ is also NP complete?

Comment: What you are saying is equivalent to: "I can't solve $Q$ in polynomial time. I can solve $P$ by solving $Q$, therefore $P$ cannot be solved in polynomial time". It does not necessarily mean $P$ cannot be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: To show NP-completeness of $P$ you need to show $Q$ is reducible to $P$ in polynomial time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not necessarily.** *Any* language in $\mathbf{P}$ is poly-time many-one reducible to *any* non-trivial language (i.e., all except $\varnothing$ or $\Sigma^\ast$); see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/109172/70382), for example. The latter language (i.e., the one you are reducing to) is, in this case, the $\mathbf{NP}$-complete $\mathcal{Q}$. For all we know, your language $\mathcal{P}$ could be any language in $\mathbf{P}$ and, therefore, not necessarily $\mathbf{NP}$-complete (even under the assumption $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{NP}$).